Python PyAV how to flush to disk regularly
I am using PyAV for encoding a video stream from a camera and saving it to disk. This works in general, but I have one problem left: the file on the disk stays at 0kb regardless of how long i record. Onyl when I close the output_stream it saves to disk.
Since I want to do hour long streams, I need to flush the stream regularly to disk. Also if my program crashes the file needs to be valid.
Here is my code for the recorder class ,which I call with "test.mkv" as output file.
class Recorder:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        recorder_instances.append(self)
        self.frame_count = 0

    def start(self, output_file, width, height, fps):
        self.output_container = av.open(output_file, mode="w")
        self.output_stream = self.output_container.add_stream("libvpx-vp9", rate=fps)
        self.output_stream.width = width
        self.output_stream.height = height
        self.output_stream.options = {
            # Add more options as needed
        }

    def recieved_frame(self, frame):
        for packet in self.output_stream.encode(frame):
            self.output_container.mux(packet)
      
    def stop(self):
        # Flush any remaining packets
        for packet in self.output_stream.encode(None):
            self.output_container.mux(packet)
        # Close the output container
        self.output_container.close()

I already tried to use:
# Flush any remaining packets
for packet in self.output_stream.encode(None):
  self.output_container.mux(packet)

...inside the recieved_frame method, but that gives me an error: "end of file" when recieving the next package.

strange: I tried to open an output file with mediaplayr and it plays a few seconds even when the the file is 0kb. After I close the media player, the file size shows a much bigger file than a few seconds (> 1 min). If i don't use mediaplayer at all, the file size stays at 0kb until I close my program

XY problem. https://xyproblem.info/ -- your file on disk isn't 0 bytes. that's just Windows Explorer lagging. PyAV/ffmpeg will write to disk when it makes sense. you should not force that. it will write to disk. it will NOT keep hours of video in RAM. trust me.

if you need files that are crash-resistant, do not use mp4 or mov. mkv is probably crash-resistant but you absolutely must verify this. if you want to be sure, use MPEG transport streams, which are .mts or .ts or .m2ts. -- even if you could force flushing the mp4 file to disk periodically, that will NOT make it readable. it only becomes readable when it's finalized. that happens once. you are solving the wrong problem the wrong way.

Your file on disk isn't 0 bytes.
That's just Windows Explorer lagging in its display of the file's size.
Press F5 to make it update its display of the file's size.

You are correct but it may take a long time. Simple test using FFmpeg CLI: ffmpeg -re -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=1920x1080:rate=25:duration=3600 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 10 -g 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mkv. I would have looked for a way for setting blocksize and flush_packets as described here. According to the documentation: blocksize
Set I/O operation maximum block size, in bytes. Default value is INT_MAX, ... Setting this value reasonably low improves user termination request reaction time, which is valuable for files on slow medium.

I tried F5, does not update. Also in powershell it always shows 0kb if I do an ls. However if I let  me show the remaining free bytes on C, I see that the number goes down. Very strange windows behaviour....
